# why does subprocess.runI(['mdfile', filename], capture_output = True).stdout return an empty string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, unix, command-line

When I run `midi.open('next.midi')` from the code

```
import subprocess
class midi:
    def __init__(self, contents):
        self.contents = contents
    def open(filename):
        subprocess.run(['mv', str(subprocess.run(
            ['mdfind', filename], capture_output = True).stdout).split(
                '\n')[0][2:-3], filename.split(
                    '.')[0] + '.txt'], capture_output = True)
        file = open(filename.split('.')[0] + '.txt')
        contents = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        midi(contents)
```

I get the error message `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'next.txt'`

after some digging, I found that `subprocess.run(['mdfind', filename], capture_output = True).stdout` returned an empty string when it should be returning the path. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

bcause you have to chage working dir of program try this

```
import os
```

after that do

```
# add this before subprocess.run
os.chdir(directory here)
```

for example your file is in a directory C:\temp\
you cannot access it directly, because it is in an other directory, therefore to access that file you has to change your directory
to that directory by `os.chdir('C:\temp\')` it will change
the directory to the directory in which that file is stored

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by directory here?

Comment: it means that in which directry your file is held for example it is /home